# How to disable double-tap in defaultCameraController?

Tags: swift, scnscene

In `SCNScene`, `allowsCameraControl` lets you move and rotate the camera, but when I "double-tap", the camera spins quickly and the object disappears.

I am reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1523171-allowscameracontrol), but I'm not sure how to disable double-tap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCNView is a subclass of UIView which has a property gestureRecognizers, an array of UIGestureRecognizers.  You can loop through this array looking for the "double-tap" gesture.  Once found, you can disable the gesture by setting isEnabled = false.

Answer (score 0):

setting `.autoSwitchToFreeCamera = false` also seems to work

```swift
lazy var sceneView: SCNView = {
    let sv = SCNView()
    sv.allowsCameraControl = true
    sv.cameraControlConfiguration.autoSwitchToFreeCamera = false
    return sv
}()
```